# как в Qt вывести число с определенной точностью после запятой, сохраняя нули

Tags: c++, qt

Сохраняю в QString число с QDoubleSpinBox, но у мена не вышло положить в QString  число с тремя знаками после запятой (а требуется именно так ).

```
    strObrabotka.append(QString("%1%2%3").arg(trUtf8("Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона  до антенны (м)   & ")).arg(ui->sb_rga->value() ).arg(trUtf8("  \\\\")));
```

пробовал так

```
    strObrabotka.append(QString("%1%2.3f%3").arg(trUtf8("Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона  до антенны (м)    & ")).arg(ui->sb_rga->value(),5).arg(trUtf8("  \\\\")));
```

получаю такой результат :"Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона до антенны (м)    5.3f"

попробовал так

```
    strObrabotka.append(QString("%1%2%3").arg(trUtf8("Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона  до антенны (м)   & ")).arg(ui->sb_rga->value(),3).arg(trUtf8("  \\\\")));
```

тоже не вышло, получаю такой результат :"Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона до антенны (м)  5 "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [QString::number](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6). Пример:

```
double n = 5.300d;
qDebug() << QString("Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона до антенны (м): %1").arg(QString::number(n, 'f', 3));
```

Вывод:

> "Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона  до антенны (м): 5.300"

Comment: метод нумбер более понятен , чем метод арг . спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
    strObrabotka.append(QString("%1%2%3").arg(trUtf8("Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона  до антенны (м)   & ")).arg(ui->sb_rga->value(), 0, 'f', 5).arg(trUtf8("  \\\\")));
```

Расстояние от излучающего гидрофона до антенны (м)  5.00000